# how to merge and update 2 Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
a1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [2,3,4]})
b2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,4], 'B': [3,6]})
```

and I wanna get

```
c = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [3,3,4,6]})
```

a1 and b2 merge on the `key='A'`
but when 'A' equal but B different, get b2 value

how can I get this work? have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First concatenate both dataframes under each other to get one big dataframe:

```
c = pd.concat([a1, b2], 0)


    A   B
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   3   4
0   1   3
1   4   6
```

Then group on column A to only get the unique values of A, by using last you make sure than when there is a duplicate the value of b2 is used. This gives:

```
c = c.groupby('A').last()


    B
A   
1   3
2   3
3   4
4   6
```

Then set reset index to get a nice numerical index.

```
c = c.reset_index()
```

which returns:

```
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   4   6
```

To do it all in one go just enter the following lines of code:

```
c = pd.concat([a1, b2], 0)
c = c.groupby('A').last().reset_index()
```